# Configure Simple Injector to inject current authenticated user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a class which needs to set an `IPrinciple` object on construction, based on the current authenticated user.

I found some other code which I tried but it didn't work:

```
private readonly Lazy<IPrincipal> _principal;

public MyService(Lazy<IPrincipal> principal)
{
    _principal = principal;
}
```

And I configured Simple Injector like so:

```
container.Register(() => new Lazy<IPrincipal>(() => HttpContext.Current.User));
```

Apparently `_principal` is undefined/not set to an instance of an object when I try running this.

I also tried:

```
container.Register(() => new Lazy<IPrincipal>(() => Thread.CurrentPrincipal));
```

This allowed me to check `_principal.Value.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but was always returning `false`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root of your problems is caused by the fact that you inject runtime data into your components during object graph construction. As explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99), this is a bad idea.

Instead, as the referenced article advices, you should delay the decision of requesting this runtime data until after the graph is built; at the time that this runtime data is available.

You can do this by creating a custom `IPrincipal` implementation like this:

```
public class HttpContextPrinciple : IPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    public bool IsInRole(string role) => HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role);
}
```

And register it like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IPrincipal>(new HttpContextPrinciple());
```

This allows you to inject `IPrincipal` directly into consumers like `MyService`. This simplifies the consumers, since they don't have to deal with [leaky abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) such as `Lazy<T>`.